# getsockname returns a Error 22, Invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, embedded

We use IPV4 socket connection over UDP.

```
 struct sockaddr_in   LocalSin;  
     int n_namelen ;
     memset( &LocalSin, 0, sizeof(LocalSin) );
     LocalSin.sin_family = AF_INET;
     LocalSin.sin_port = htons(1050);
    socketS = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
     if ( bind(socketS, (struct sockaddr *)&LocalSin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) != RTCS_OK  )
          {
    //socket bind error
        }
n_namelen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if ( getsockname( socketS, (struct sockaddr *)&LocalSin,(socklen_t *) &n_namelen) != RTCS_OK)
          {
    //getsockname error
    }
```

Here socket function succeeds, also the bind succeeds, but , getsockname fails with error 22, occasionally(mostly), but succeeds few times.. The environment is Linux 3.0.35. Any suggestions?

Note: the OS has both IPV6 and IPV4 enabled

Note - Progress: the sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) comes as 16. Which can never be when we check its definition in the in.h . Any clue?

Comment: What is `RTCS_OK`? And are you sure the `socket` call succeeded?

Comment: You've used the `socketS` without checking the success of `socket()` call.

Comment: Yes, socket call & bind call succeeds promptly

Comment: also, you can safely get rid of the casts in `getsockname()`.

Comment: ok, but does that do any difference?

Comment: If you [read the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) the error `EINVAL` (which you get) is because the length argument is invalid. So my questions now are, is the code you show your *actual* code? Is it how you *really* set `n_namelen`? Is it really *that* piece of code that gives you the error?

Comment: yes, the n_namelen is set in same way, and almost the same code.

Comment: what does "almost" mean ? Why not show the actual code ? A thought : are you always setting `n_namelen` right before every `getsockname` call ? Or are you somehow re-using that variable ? In the latter case, that could be your issue, since `getsockname` can modify it.

Comment: `n_namelen` should be of type `socklen_t`. Using `int` will definitely fail if the sizes differ.

Comment: The variable names would be diff, thats it, yes yes n_namelen is used only once and set right before call of getsockname.

Comment: the strange behaviour noted is sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) comes as 16. Strange behaviour!? . Any clue anyone?